# Re-ordering variable width bars withing ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Hi I am making a variable width bar graph and would like to order the bars from tallest to smallest. The order of the bars often change when I run the code. [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POmmH.png)

Here is my code

```
df<-data.frame(Project=datafram$Project,Capex=datafram$Capex,width=datafram$Capex, Emissions=datafram$Emissions)
df$w <- cumsum(df$width) #cumulative sums.
df$wm <- df$w - df$width
df$Emissions<- with(df, wm + (w - wm)/2)
p  <- ggplot(df, aes(ymin = 0))
p1 <- p + geom_rect(aes(xmin = wm, xmax = w, ymax = Emissions, fill = Project))
p2<-p1 + geom_text(aes(x = wm + Capex/2, y = Emissions, label = Project), size=4, nudge_y =-300, angle = 60) 
p3<-p2+labs(title = "Abatement Curve", x = "CAPEX", y = "Capital Efficiency")
blue.bold.italic.10.text <- element_text(color = "black", size = 16)
p4<-p3+theme(axis.title = blue.bold.italic.10.text, title =blue.bold.italic.10.text)
g=p4;
```

Here is my data 
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LWSU.png)

I'm not sure what function to use or how to do so. Pls help

Comment: Run this and then plot: levels(df$Project) <- c("six", "five", "four", "three", "two", "one")

Comment: Is there any way to automate it, so I doesn't matter the names of the projects?

Comment: in aes try: fill = reorder(Project, -Emission) can you update the structure of the data using dput(data), so that I could test it and add the answer?

Comment: That did not work, it changed the legend label to be "reorder(Project, - Emissions)